Convert A-H to ABCDEFGH VB.Net
I am developing a program, in which the end user enters a string (A-B, A-C, A-D... A-Z), this string would be converted for example...
If it is A-C, the string would be converted to ABC and in turn generate three text files with certain information (FileA, FileB and FileC) and so on for the other strings.
If stringC = "A-C" then
    stringC = "ABC"
elseif stringC = "A-D" then
    stringC = "ABCD"
...
elseif stringC = "A-Z" then
    stringC = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
End If

I was thinking of developing it by using conditionals (if ... then ... elseif ... End If) that identify each string, but I would be left with a very extensive tree of conditionals if it went up to A-Z. Any ideas to simplify it?
Regards, thank you in advance.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions

you can use substring, if you pass in something like "D-X" use split then get the index of D and the index of X.
here is the fiddle. https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ag0S81
  Dim alphabet As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
      
        Dim GetAlphabetRange As Func(Of String, String) = Function(query As String) _
            alphabet.Substring(
                alphabet.IndexOf(Char.Parse(query.Split("-"c)(0))),
                alphabet.IndexOf(Char.Parse(query.Split("-"c)(1))) - 
                alphabet.IndexOf(Char.Parse(query.Split("-"c)(0))) + 1)

        ' Test the function with different ranges
        Console.WriteLine(GetAlphabetRange("A-N"))
        Console.WriteLine(GetAlphabetRange("C-F"))
        Console.WriteLine(GetAlphabetRange("X-Z"))


it´s works. thank you so much!!!!

This solution uses a Dictionary to store the search & replace text pairs. It uses a loop to fill the array, but you could also hardcode other pairs.
We then use a loop to apply the replacements. StringBuilder is used instead of String in places for performance reasons.
' Set up a Dictionary with replacement text
Dim replacements As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
For i = 3 To 26
  Dim search = "A-" & Char.ConvertFromUtf32(64 + i)
  Dim replacement As New StringBuilder
  For j = 1 To i
    replacement.Append(Char.ConvertFromUtf32(64 + j))
  Next j
  replacements.Add(search, replacement.ToString)
Next i

Dim documentText As New StringBuilder("First fifteen letters of the alphabet are A-O, while the first eight are A-H")

' Use the Dictionary to replace the text
For Each replacement In replacements
  documentText.Replace(replacement.Key, replacement.Value)
Next replacement
Console.WriteLine(documentText)


Assuming your input string stringC always starts with A, and and has correct format of A-X, you can use string Split method to get the last character. Then you can get the index n of the last characted in the string representing the alphabet, ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ. Finally, you can get first n symbols from the alphabet to get the expanded version of the input string.
The code would be something like this (please verify with your VB compiler, I don't have one handy right now)
Dim startEnd as String() = stringC.Split('-')
Dim lastLetter = startEnd(1)
Dim alphabet as String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
Dim n as Integer = alphabet.IndexOf(lastLetter)
Dim result = alphabet.Substring(0, n) '// or maby n+1, test it

